# How to compare Sql datetime field with date field

Tags: mysql, query

I have `datetime` type column in `sql table`name id `created`and i get date from `input date type html tag` I want to compare in `sql query where close condition`. How to compare both field.

```
var startDate = $('#startDate').val();

'.... where created >='+ startDate;
```

Comment: Questions of this type belong on StackOverflow and are off topic here. Though it's most likely a duplicate there of one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843395/compare-two-datetime-only-by-date-not-time-in-sql-server-2008 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958829/sql-server-compare-datetime-day-with-getdate

Comment: I read all question but not work in my condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... I *get date from input date type html tag*

I'll wager you *don't*. 
Html tags tend to return **String** values.

You have to *parse* (and, in this case, *format*) that [String] value before using it in SQL.

Why Parse?  Because the Html Control returns a String and you need a Date.

Why Format?  Because that Date value needs to be represented in the format of a SqlServer Date literal for your comparison to work.

Better still, start using Parameterised Queries.  You'll still need to parse the value into a Date[Time] variable, but at least you'll lose the formatting part of the job (the parameter will take care of that for you).